# C# Forms - Loading images

Tags: c#, forms, radio-button, picturebox

I'm trying to load a specific image in my picture box *if* a specific radio button is checked.

The  run-time error was a "_Couldn't locate file in this directory.", so I moved the images to that directory, but that just caused the picture box to load it automatically.
I've also imported all of the images I need as well.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        pictureBox1.Load("10C.jpg");
    }
}
```

When I run the program `pictureBox1` had already loaded the image. What I want my `pictureBox1` to do is remain blank until the user selects a radio button and clicks the "change image" button.

Comment: *that just caused the picture box to load it automatically* - What exactly does that mean??

Comment: When I run the program pictureBox1 had already loaded the image. What I want my pictureBox1 to do is remain blank until user selects a radioButton and selects the "change image" button.

Comment: Did you set the `image` property for the pictureBox1 in the designer?

Comment: Use `Application.ExePath` to figure out where the image is with respect to the application and load based on an absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

You should place `pictureBox1.Visible = false;` in the form load event

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it so that pictureBox1.Visible = false; 
Then you could say:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (radioButton1.Checked)
     {
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        pictureBox1.Load("10C.jpg");
     }
}
```

This way the image is not seen until the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to set a default image in picture box at startup and if a radiobutton is checked and a button is clicked load the `desired image` (10C.jpg) into picture box instead of dealing with the `visible` property of the picture box.

The code will look like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // pictureBox1.Visible will be always set to true
   if (radioButton1.Checked)
   {
        pictureBox1.Load("10C.jpg");
   }
   else
   {
        pictureBox1.Load("placeholder.jpg");
   }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    pictureBox1.Load("placeholder.jpg");
}
```

Recommended: search google for `placeholder image`

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

In response of:

> The run-time error was a "_Couldn't locate file in this directory.",
>   so I moved the images to that directory, but that just caused the
>   picture box to load it automatically. I've also imported all of the
>   images I need as well.

Define a key in config file that holds an image path and use it to access your images by concatenating filename at the end. With this approach you can change image path even after deployment.